# How to update object property which is an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I am working in a ReactJS project and have a `filterGroupsData` property in my state. This is an array of objects, each object has a `filters` property which is an array of string values. See below:

```
filterGroupsData:[
    {"key":1532957059388,"id":1532957059388,"filters":[]},        
    {"key":1532957059612,"id":1532957059612,"filters":[]},        
    {"key":1532957059847,"id":1532957059847,"filters":[]}
]
```

How can I add elements to the filters property of a object with a given id?

I attempted to this but this results in overwriting the whole object with on value:

```
// update the filter array of the object with id == activeId
let updatedFilterGroupsData = filterGroupsData.map(filterGroupData => filterGroupData.id === activeId ? filterGroupData.filters.push('test') : filterGroupData)

this.setState({filterGroupsData: updatedFilterGroupsData});
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the index of the filter group you want to update, and then create a copy of the object and the `filters` array and add a new entry to it.

**Example**

```
const id = 1532957059388;

this.setState(previousState => {
  const filterGroupsData = [...previousState.filterGroupsData];
  const index = filterGroupsData.findIndex(group => group.id === id);

  filterGroupsData[index] = {
    ...filterGroupsData[index],
    filters: [...filterGroupsData[index].filters, "new filter"]
  };

  return { filterGroupsData };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: `filterGroupData.filters = 'test'`

You're setting the prop value to a string instead of putting in the array.

You need to `push` the item into the `filters` array like:

`filterGroupData.filters.push('test');`

Comment: Apologies - I had actually spotted this before I had posted my question and amended it but forgot to update my question.

Answer (score 0):

`filters` is a array so you need to use `push('test')` with multi line code inside `map`:

```js
var filterGroupsData = [
    {"key":1532957059388,"id":1532957059388,"filters":[]},        
    {"key":1532957059612,"id":1532957059612,"filters":[]},        
    {"key":1532957059847,"id":1532957059847,"filters":[]}
]
var activeId = 1532957059612;
let updatedFilterGroupsData = filterGroupsData.map((filterGroupData) => {
  if(filterGroupData.id === activeId) {
      filterGroupData.filters.push('test');
  }
  return filterGroupData 
});
console.log(updatedFilterGroupsData);
```